# Convert values in a column to column headers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pivot-table

I have the following code, which takes the values in one column of a pandas dataframe and makes them the columns of a new data frame. The values in the first column of the dataframe become the index of the new dataframe.

In a sense, I want to turn an adjacency list into an adjacency matrix. Here's the code so far:

```py
import pandas as pa
# Create a dataframe
oldcols = {'col1':['a','a','b','b'], 'col2':['c','d','c','d'], 'col3':[1,2,3,4]}
a = pa.DataFrame(oldcols)

# The columns of the new data frame will be the values in col2 of the original
newcols = list(set(oldcols['col2']))
rows = list(set(oldcols['col1']))

# Create the new data matrix
data = np.zeros((len(rows), len(newcols)))

# Iterate over each row and fill in the new matrix
for row in zip(a['col1'], a['col2'], a['col3']):
    rowindex = rows.index(row[0])
    colindex = newcols.index(row[1])
    data[rowindex][colindex] = row[2]

newf = pa.DataFrame(data)
newf.columns = newcols
newf.index = rows
```

This works for this particular instance as follows: The original DataFrame

```
  col1 col2  col3
0    a    c     1
1    a    d     2
2    b    c     3
3    b    d     4
```

is transformed to a new DataFrame that looks like

```
   c  d
a  1  2
b  3  4
```

It will fail if the values in col3 are not numbers. My question is, is there a more elegant/robust way of doing this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This looks like [a job for pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-and-pivot-tables):

```
import pandas as pd
oldcols = {'col1':['a','a','b','b'], 'col2':['c','d','c','d'], 'col3':[1,2,3,4]}
a = pd.DataFrame(oldcols)  

newf = a.pivot(index='col1', columns='col2')
print(newf)
```

yields

```
      col3   
col2     c  d
col1         
a        1  2
b        3  4
```

If you don't want a MultiIndex column, you can drop the `col3` using:

```
newf.columns = newf.columns.droplevel(0)
```

which would then yield

```
col2  c  d
col1      
a     1  2
b     3  4
```

Comment: Wow, *almost* makes me regret writing up the code to do it 'manually' :-P

Comment: Don't worry -- it makes you appreciate pandas even more!

Comment: @unutbu I have almost same case however there are duplicates, how can i take care of them. So, here it means that suppose col2 is having duplicates, what needs to be done in that case.

Comment: @RishiBansal: Use [df.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) when there are duplicates. It has an `aggfunc` parameter which allows you to specify how you wish to aggregate the duplicates into a single value. Or, you could [drop the duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) before calling `df.pivot`.

Answer (score 0):

As @unutbu mentioned, you can reshape the dataframe using `pivot`.

```py
res = a.pivot(index='col1', columns='col2', values='col3')
```

An even more terse way is to unpack column labels as args.

```py
res = a.pivot(*a).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
```

[image: res]

---

Another method is to explicitly construct a graph object (using the popular graph library `networkx`) and construct an adjacency matrix. It's probably too verbose for a simple pivot operation but if the given data is already in graph form, it could be useful.

```py
import networkx as nx
g = nx.Graph()
col1 = a['col1'].unique()
col2 = a['col2'].unique()
g.add_weighted_edges_from(list(map(tuple, a.values)))
res = nx.to_pandas_adjacency(g).loc[col1, col2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way is to assign the first two columns as MultiIndex and then unstack the second column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','b','b'], 'col2':['c','d','c','d'], 'col3':[1,2,3,4]}) 
df.set_index(['col1', 'col2']).squeeze().unstack('col2')
```

results in

```
col2  c  d
col1      
a     1  2
b     3  4
```

The `squeeze()` method converts a DataFrame with a single column into a Series.