# Pandas: Pivot column to headers

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I'm trying to pivot the values in a column to column headers, but maintain the rest of the data.  Here's my full code, along with the closest I can get to what I'm looking for.  The only problem with this is that I can't figure out how to keep the `end` column:

```
import pandas as pd

starts = pd.date_range(start = '1/1/2017', freq = '31d', periods = 4).tolist()
ends = pd.date_range(start = '1/31/2017', freq = '31d', periods = 4).tolist()

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id':['XXX','XXX','XXX','XXX','YYY','YYY','YYY','YYY'], 
                    'start': starts + starts,
                    'end': ends + ends,
                    'type':['car','car','car','car','truck','truck','truck','truck']
                    }, columns = ['id','start','end','type'])
```

**Original Dataframe:**

```
    id      start        end   type
0  XXX 2017-01-01 2017-01-31    car
1  XXX 2017-02-01 2017-03-03    car
2  XXX 2017-03-04 2017-04-03    car
3  XXX 2017-04-04 2017-05-04    car
4  YYY 2017-01-01 2017-01-31  truck
5  YYY 2017-02-01 2017-03-03  truck
6  YYY 2017-03-04 2017-04-03  truck
7  YYY 2017-04-04 2017-05-04  truck
```

**My closest current pivot attempt:**

```
print df.pivot(index = 'start', columns = 'id', values = 'type').reset_index()
```

**Current output:**

```
id      start  XXX    YYY
0  2017-01-01  car  truck
1  2017-02-01  car  truck
2  2017-03-04  car  truck
3  2017-04-04  car  truck
```

**Desired output:**

```
        start         end  XXX    YYY
0  2017-01-01  2017-01-31  car  truck
1  2017-02-01  2017-03-03  car  truck
2  2017-03-04  2017-04-03  car  truck
3  2017-04-04  2017-05-04  car  truck
```

I've tried both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255671/pandas-column-values-to-columns) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173572/change-column-values-to-column-headers-in-pandas), with no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using set_index and unstack,

```
df.set_index(['start', 'end', 'id']).type.unstack().reset_index()



id  start       end         XXX YYY
0   2017-01-01  2017-01-31  car truck
1   2017-02-01  2017-03-03  car truck
2   2017-03-04  2017-04-03  car truck
3   2017-04-04  2017-05-04  car truck
```

Comment: I very slightly updated the question to remove the "id" column name as the index.  Solution was to add `.rename_axis(None, axis = 1)` to the end.

Answer (score 7):

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['start','end'],columns='id',values='type',aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
Out[1587]: 
id       start         end  XXX    YYY
0   2017-01-01  2017-01-31  car  truck
1   2017-02-01  2017-03-03  car  truck
2   2017-03-04  2017-04-03  car  truck
3   2017-04-04  2017-05-04  car  truck
```

Comment: Nice, I guess pivot_table should be preferred

Comment: @Vaishali - why do you say `pivot_table` would be preferred?

Comment: Because you have a function that does the same thing so may be more pythonic

Comment: @pshep123 it have the `aggfunc` in the end , You can also agg the value by groupby when you are using unstack, but that is one more step .. and groupby is time costing function .